# phpMyAdmin username wildcard of '%' in Host-based authentication

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have read on the FAQ of phpmyadmin.net under section 4.6, that I can use the % wildcard to limit users who have access.

> 4.6 How can I use the Host-based authentication additions?
>
> If you have existing rules from an old .htaccess file, you can take
>   them and add a username between the 'deny'/'allow' and 'from' strings.
>   Using the username wildcard of '%' would be a major benefit here if
>   your installation is suited to using it. Then you can just add those
>   updated lines into the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']
>   array.

Now I'd like to limit access to users who have a certain prefix in name, for example 123_% and deny everything else.

I tried adding the following to the config.inc.php under the "/* Server Parameters */":

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'deny,allow';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array(
    'deny from all',
    'allow 123_% from all',
);
```

Tried also a 'deny % from all' or inverting the 'deny,allow' order, but nothing seems to work. Or does it just not work this way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you've technically misunderstood the purpose here. `%` isn't meant to be used with partial usernames, it's to replace *any* username.

So valid rules would be things like:

```php
'allow root from 127.0.0.1',  # allow root to only access from 127.0.0.1
'allow isaac from all',       # allow isaac access from any IP address
'allow % from 198.51.100.17', # allow any user to connect from 198.51.100.17
```

Unfortunately, the current implementation doesn't recognize the use of partial username matches with a wildcard character. I don't imagine that would be too difficult to add, so if it's important to you it might be worth [opening a feature request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/new?template=feature_request.md).